# Migrating Ubuntu 18.04.03 from HDD to SSD

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, migration

Currently, I am running Ubuntu 18.04.03 on a 1TB hard drive and I would like to move Ubuntu to my 256 GB SSD for booting. I would like to put some files on the SSD and keep some on the HDD as well. Furthermore, I would like to keep Windows on the HDD. What is the best way of doing this process? (There is nothing on the SSD that I would need to keep.)

EDIT: There is also a copy of windows on the SSD. I would like to copy over Windows to the HDD before I format the SSD.

Below is an image of my disk partitions in Gparted.
[System Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxJLF.png)

Here is the output of `fdisk -l` (the part about partitions).

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 20382797-872E-40E8-8700-5D36162941E6

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2      534528     796671    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3      796672  964498167 963701496 459.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1887537152 1889585151   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  1889585152 1952499711  62914560    30G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  1952499712 1953421311    921600   450M Lenovo boot partition
/dev/sda7   964499456 1887537151 923037696 440.1G Linux filesystem
```

Here is the output of `df`.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             6099764         0   6099764   0% /dev
tmpfs            1224388      2036   1222352   1% /run
/dev/sda7      453224936 113265440 316867172  27% /
tmpfs            6121936    217288   5904648   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            6121936         0   6121936   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0          1024      1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/73
/dev/loop4          1024      1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop1         67584     67584         0 100% /snap/discord/93
/dev/loop5        144128    144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/92
/dev/loop6        153600    153600         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop8        150912    150912         0 100% /snap/obs-studio/604
/dev/loop11        36224     36224         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop20         4224      4224         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop13         3840      3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/95
/dev/loop14        15104     15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/317
/dev/loop9         55808     55808         0 100% /snap/core18/1144
/dev/loop16       144128    144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/90
/dev/loop19         4352      4352         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/501
/dev/loop17         3840      3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop18        15104     15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/loop2        153600    153600         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop7         43904     43904         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop10        55808     55808         0 100% /snap/core18/1098
/dev/loop12        90880     90880         0 100% /snap/core/7396
/dev/loop15        91264     91264         0 100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/loop3        151552    151552         0 100% /snap/obs-studio/525
/dev/sda1         262144     33892    228252  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1224384        12   1224372   1% /run/user/124
tmpfs            1224384        28   1224356   1% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98754/discussion-on-question-by-blcraft-gaming-migrating-ubuntu-18-04-03-from-hdd-to-s).